# How to add navigation drawer to the nativescript android app developed in visual studio and javascript version

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

How to add navigation drawer to the nativescript android app. I am developing android application using native script in visual studio and javascript template.
I couldn't add navigation drawer to the application. I tried copy pasting the NEXT sample app for the side bar portion, but couldn't get it building. I am facing issue for the same. 
Please help me out. Any suggestions and leads will also be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar, which they're using in the example, is a (payed) [controller from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/ios-ui/sidedrawer). As such, it needs to be payed for, downloaded, and added to your project.